# C# calculation of RSI gives Problems

Tags: c#, calculation

RSI calulation gives all sort of problems (errors)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using ExchangeSharp;

namespace DayTradeScanner
{
    public class RelativeStrengthIndex
    {
        public RelativeStrengthIndex(List<MarketCandle> candles, int candle, int length = 14)
        {
            var prices1 = candles.Skip(candle).Select(e => e.ClosePrice).Take(length).ToList();
            var prices2 = candles.Skip(candle).Select(e => e.ClosePrice).Take(length - 1).ToList();
            double sumGain = 0;
            double sumLoss = 0;
            {
                difference = (prices1 - prices2);
                if (difference >= 0)
                {
                    sumGain += difference;
                }
                else
                {
                    sumLoss -= difference;
                }
            }

            if (sumGain == 0) return 0;
            if (Math.Abs(sumLoss) < Tolerance) return 100;
            var relativeStrength = sumGain / sumLoss;

            return 100 - (100 / (1 + relativeStrength));

        }


        public decimal sumGain { get;  internal set; }
        public decimal sumLoss { get; internal set; }
        public decimal relativeStrength { get; internal set; }
        public decimal difference { get; internal set; }
    }
}
```

Error 1
Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'List' and 'List'  Line 19

Error 2
Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'decimal'  Line 22

Error 3
Operator '-=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'decimal'  line 26

Error 4
Since 'RelativeStrengthIndex.RelativeStrengthIndex(List, int, int)' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression   Line 30

Error 5
The name 'Tolerance' does not exist in the current context  Line 31

Error 6
Since 'RelativeStrengthIndex.RelativeStrengthIndex(List, int, int)' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression   Line 34 Active

Error 7
Since 'RelativeStrengthIndex.RelativeStrengthIndex(List, int, int)' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression   Line 34 Active

All sort of the same error, but do not know how to fix it.

Comment: Is the a homework task?

Comment: What does it mean to subtract one list from another?  `-` is a math operation.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really clear what you're trying to do, which makes it hard to suggest how to fix some of these...

Error 1: `prices1` and `prices2` are both lists (see how you call `ToList()` at the ends of the lines which initialise them?). You then do `(prices1 - prices2)`, but you can't subtract two lists. What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Error 2: `difference` is a `decimal` (see `public decimal difference { get; internal set; }`), but `sumGain` is a `double`. You probably want them to both be `double`, or both be `decimal`. Decide which data type you want to use, and use it for both.

Error 3: Same, but with `someLoss` instead of `someGain`.

Error 4: You're defining a constructor, but constructors can't return values. Did you mean to define a normal method, instead of a constructor?

Error 5: You haven't defined `Tolerance`. Did you mean to define it (perhaps as a const)?

Error 6: Same as error 4

Error 7: Same as error 4

Comment: Error 1 - Price1 has a length (a period) of 14 . Price 2 has a lenght (a period of 14 -1).

the calculation of RSI (Relative Strength index):
RSI = 100 – [100 / ( 1 + (Average of Upward Price Change / Average of Downward Price Change ) ) ]
And want to get it run in c# The data is from exchnagesharp.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello, here is working and verified C# class that calculates RSI values with 100% accuracy:**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Globalization;

namespace YourNameSpace
  {
   class PriceEngine
      {
        public static DataTable data;
        public static double[] positiveChanges;
        public static double[] negativeChanges;
        public static double[] averageGain;
        public static double[] averageLoss;
        public static double[] rsi;
        
        public static double CalculateDifference(double current_price, double previous_price)
          {
              return current_price - previous_price;
          }

        public static double CalculatePositiveChange(double difference)
          {
              return difference > 0 ? difference : 0;
          }

        public static double CalculateNegativeChange(double difference)
          {
              return difference < 0 ? difference * -1 : 0;
          }

        public static void CalculateRSI(int rsi_period, int price_index = 5)
          {
              for(int i = 0; i < PriceEngine.data.Rows.Count; i++)
              {
                  double current_difference = 0.0;
                  if (i > 0)
                  {
                      double previous_close = Convert.ToDouble(PriceEngine.data.Rows[i-1].Field<string>(price_index));
                      double current_close = Convert.ToDouble(PriceEngine.data.Rows[i].Field<string>(price_index));
                      current_difference = CalculateDifference(current_close, previous_close);
                  }
                  PriceEngine.positiveChanges[i] = CalculatePositiveChange(current_difference);
                  PriceEngine.negativeChanges[i] = CalculateNegativeChange(current_difference);

                  if(i == Math.Max(1,rsi_period))
                  {
                      double gain_sum = 0.0;
                      double loss_sum = 0.0;
                      for(int x = Math.Max(1,rsi_period); x > 0; x--)
                      {
                          gain_sum += PriceEngine.positiveChanges[x];
                          loss_sum += PriceEngine.negativeChanges[x];
                      }

                      PriceEngine.averageGain[i] = gain_sum / Math.Max(1,rsi_period);
                      PriceEngine.averageLoss[i] = loss_sum / Math.Max(1,rsi_period);

                  }else if (i > Math.Max(1,rsi_period))
                  {
                      PriceEngine.averageGain[i] = ( PriceEngine.averageGain[i-1]*(rsi_period-1) + PriceEngine.positiveChanges[i]) / Math.Max(1, rsi_period);
                      PriceEngine.averageLoss[i] = ( PriceEngine.averageLoss[i-1]*(rsi_period-1) + PriceEngine.negativeChanges[i]) / Math.Max(1, rsi_period);
                      PriceEngine.rsi[i] = PriceEngine.averageLoss[i] == 0 ? 100 : PriceEngine.averageGain[i] == 0 ? 0 : Math.Round(100 - (100 / (1 + PriceEngine.averageGain[i] / PriceEngine.averageLoss[i])), 5);
                  }
              }
          }
          
        public static void Launch()
          {
            PriceEngine.data = new DataTable();            
            //load {date, time, open, high, low, close} values in PriceEngine.data (6th column (index #5) = close price) here
            
            positiveChanges = new double[PriceEngine.data.Rows.Count];
            negativeChanges = new double[PriceEngine.data.Rows.Count];
            averageGain = new double[PriceEngine.data.Rows.Count];
            averageLoss = new double[PriceEngine.data.Rows.Count];
            rsi = new double[PriceEngine.data.Rows.Count];
            
            CalculateRSI(14);
          }
          
      }
  }
```

**For detailed step-by-step instructions, I wrote a lengthy article, you can check it here:**
https://turmanauli.medium.com/a-step-by-step-guide-for-calculating-reliable-rsi-values-programmatically-a6a604a06b77